# Логи дискорд боту

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Делаю бота, столкнулся с проблемой, нужно делать логи, искал в документации, на других сайтах, единственное что я находил, так это код который выдаёт ошибки и прочее...Требуется вывести аудит в определенный чат, вместе с подробностями(По типу какое содержание было у сообщения которое удалили и т.д.) Есть ли какие то русские ресурсы чтобы подробнее почитать об этом, или код как можно сделать логи и чтобы бот их отправлял?

P.S. На офф. документации нашёл что то похожее на логи, но это не то что мне нужно.

Вот что я делал в попытках написать логи

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Логирования пользователей

Это можно сделать через `event`

К примеру, если вы хотите что бы каждое сообщение которое отправляется в чат отображалось в консоле, тогда используйте [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message: ', message.content)# содержимое сообщения
    print('Member: ', message.member)# кто отправил сообщение
```

Также вы можете посмотреть что содержит в себе `message`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)# просто напишите что-то в чат и посмотрите в консоль
```

Хотите узнать что происходит с пользователем, к примеру, какую роль он получил, делайте через [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member_update#discord.on_member_update):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print(before.member.top_role)#выведет самую высокую роль до изменения
    print(after.member.top_role)#выведет самую высокую роль после изменения
```

Также можете посмотреть что содержит в себе переменные `before` и `after`

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    print('Before: ', before)
    print('After', after)
```

Больше методов можете посмотреть [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=on_member#)

## Логирования самого сервера

Тут уже больше возможностей, я покажу несколько, а ссылку на остальные я оставлю снизу.

И так начнем с [on_guild_channel_create](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_channel_create)(посмотреть что содержит в себе `channel` можете так само как я показывал пару раз с верху):

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    print('Channel name: ', channel.name)#выведет имя канала
    print('Channel category: ', channel.category)#выведет категорию где он находится
    print('Channel id: ', channel.id)#выведет айди канала
    print('Channel created at', channel.created_at)#выведет час и дату когда он был создан
```

На очереди в нас [on_guild_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_update), этот метод может вам выдавать:

1. Изменения названия сервера
2. Изменен канала AFK
3. Изменение тайм-аута AFK канала
4. и т.д.

   ```
   @client.event
   async def on_guild_update(before, after):
       print('Before guild name: ', before.guild.name)
       print('After guild name: ', after.guild.name)

       print('Before guild banner_url: ', before.guild.banner_url)#банер сервера до
       print('After guild banner_url: ', after.guild.banner_url)#банер сервера после

       print('Before guild icon_url: ', before.guild.icon_url)#значок сервера до
       print('After guild icon_url: ', after.guild.icon_url)#значок сервера после
   ```

И на последок [on_guild_role_created](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_role_create)

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_role_created(role):
    print('Role name:', role.name)#имя роли
    print('Role color:', role.color)#цвет роли
    print('Role id:', role.id)#айди роли
    print('Role permissions:', role.permissions)#разрешения роли
    print('Role created_at:', role.created_at)#когда роль была создана
```

[Больше методов для логирования сервера](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=on_guild#)

### Вывод сообщений в отдельный канал

К примеру возьмем `on_message`(но перед этим вам надо импортировать утилиты discord'а)

```
from discord import utils
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel()#здесь айди канала куда будет отправляться сообщение
    await channel.send(message.content, message.member)
```

Comment: можно ли эти логи вывести в определенный канал? Попробовал - к сожалению не получилось.

Comment: Да, сейчас исправлю ответ

Comment: Изменил, посмотрите.