# Вывод информации кто создал при создании текстового канала Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    em = discord.Embed(color=COLORS["hidden"])
    em = discord.Embed(
        title='Создан текстовый канал',
        timestamp=datetime.utcnow()
        )
    em.add_field(
        name='Название',
        value=f'[{channel.name} | <#{channel.id}>]'
        )
  
    await channels.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html <------ Тут все ответы на все ваши вопросы

Comment: И  пожалуйста нормально оформите ваш вопрос, в нем не понятно что вы хотите, и что у вас не вышло. На вопрос такого оформления никто нормальный ответ не даст

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Логи дискорд боту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237847/%d0%9b%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

Первое что хотелось бы сказать, вопрос понятен, но стоило более подробно описать проблему/что хочется сделать. На stackoverflow уже был подобный вопрос, где всё подробно рассказано, но, я пожалуй продублирую сюда.

## Логирование сервера

[on_guild_channel_create](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_channel_create)

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    print('Channel name: ', channel.name)#выведет имя канала
    print('Channel category: ', channel.category)#выведет категорию где он находится
    print('Channel id: ', channel.id)#выведет айди канала
    print('Channel created at', channel.created_at)#выведет час и дату когда он был создан
```

Также есть код, который будет отправлять эти логи в определенный канал

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel()#здесь айди канала куда будет отправляться сообщение
    await channel.send(message.content, message.member)
```

Ещё есть официальная [документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#event-reference) по discord.py, где можно вычитать абсолютно всю информацию про события

А вот похожий [вопрос по логам на stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237847/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83)

Comment: Но мне нужно отследить кто создал канал.